# After upgrading my 18.04 LT to 4.15.-52-generic can't boot on LUKS encrypted LVM

Tags: boot, kernel, lvm, luks

After upgrading my 18.04 LTE to 4.15.-52-generic kernel modules I am not able to boot into my Desktop. My SSD is LUKS encrypted (LUKS partition on LVM). With the new kernel modules, it doesn't ask me to enter the password to unlock. I end up in a busybox shell.

Going to advanced settings on boot, selecting the 4.15.-51 it does ask me for the password and boots just fine.

I'm a bit lost on where to look in the logs to find a possible cause. I have also not found anything related to my issues. Which direction should I look to fix the issue and/or should I address it somewhere else?

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs -v -u -k 4.15.-52-generic` maybe shows a hint. This updates only not working  kernel-version.

Comment: That indeed did help, the system now works as expected, asks for the password and then boots normally. `uname -r` shows `4.15.0-52-generic`. Thanks for your help!